# Exclude a file or a list of files from being copied during Maven build process

Tags: maven, pom.xml

How to exclude a file from being copied during maven build process :

```
<copy todir="target/classes/META-INF/config" overwrite="true" failonerror="false">
    <fileset dir="src/main/resources/"  />
    <!-- something like <fileset dir="src/main/resources/" excludes="fileA.properties" /> for excluding fileA.properties from being copied to the target folder -->
</copy>
```

Comment: Hm..you are showing a an Antscript snipped ? What have you tried to far? And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I guess I have found the solution. I had actually to just use what I have put as comment. In fact, the "excludes" attribute works.

Comment: Sorry this looks really wrong in a Maven build..but unfortunately you haven't answered my questions...